# How to calculate the average number of days between the first and the second order in a dataframe which contains more than 2 orders per client?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
  id_cliente    id_ordine data_ordine id_medium
0  madinside  IML-0042758  2016-08-23   1190408
1  lisbeth19  IML-0071225  2017-02-26   1205650
2  lisbeth19  IML-0072944  2017-03-15   1207056
3  lisbeth19  IML-0077676  2017-05-12   1211395
4  lisbeth19  IML-0077676  2017-05-12   1207056
5  madinside  IML-0094979  2017-09-29   1222195
6  lisbeth19  IML-0099675  2017-11-15   1211446
7  lisbeth19  IML-0099690  2017-11-15   1225212
8  lisbeth19  IML-0101439  2017-12-02   1226511
9  lisbeth19  IML-0109883  2018-03-14   1226511
```

I would like to add three columns:

- the first column could be named **"number of order per client"** and should be the progression of orders made by the same client.
  So order *IML-0042758* should be 1, *IML-0071225* should be 1, *IML-0072944* should be 2, *IML-0077676* should be 3, *IML-0094979* should be 2, and so on..
- the second column could be named **"days between first and n order of the same client"** and shows the the **"data_ordine"** difference (a datetime column) between the different orders made by the same client.
  So the values for the first 6 rows would be: 0 (2016-08-23 - 2016-08-23), 0 (2017-02-26 - 2017-02-26), 17 (2017-03-15 - 2017-02-26), 75 (2017-05-12 - 2017-02-26), 75 (2017-05-12 - 2017-02-26), 402 (2017-09-29 - 2017-02-26).
- the third column could be named **"days between first and n order of the same id_medium"** and shows the the **"data_ordine"** difference (a datetime column) between the different orders per *id_medium*.
  So the values for the first 6 rows would be: 0 (2016-08-23 - 2016-08-23), 0 (2017-02-26 - 2017-02-26), 0 (2017-03-15 - 2017-03-15), 0 (2017-05-12 - 2017-05-12), 58 (2017-05-12 - 2017-03-15 because  the medium *"1207056"* is ordered for the second time), 0 (2017-09-29 - 2017-09-29).

In the end I would like to calculate how long it takes in average for a client to make a second order, a third order, a fourth order and so on.
And how long it takes in average for a client to make a second, third (etc.) order for the same id_medium.

Comment: You're right, there is an error on last difference: because the client for index 5 is  madinside  the difference should have been 2017-09-29 - 2016-08-23. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert to `datetime` and `sort` so the calculations are reliable.

- The first column we can use `groupby` + `ngroup` to label each order, then we subtract the min from each person so they all start from 1
- Days from 1st order, use `groupby` + `transform` to get the first date of each client then subtract
- Third column is the same, just add `id_medium` to the grouping

#### Code:

```
df['data_ordine'] = pd.to_datetime(df['data_ordine']) 
df = df.sort_values('data_ordine')

df['Num_ords'] = df.groupby(['id_cliente', 'id_ordine']).ngroup()
df['Num_ords'] = df.Num_ords - df.groupby(['id_cliente']).Num_ords.transform('min')+1

df['days_bet'] = (df.data_ordine -df.groupby('id_cliente').data_ordine.transform('min')).dt.days

df['days_bet_id'] = (df.data_ordine - df.groupby(['id_cliente', 'id_medium']).data_ordine.transform('min')).dt.days
```

#### Output:

```
  id_cliente    id_ordine data_ordine  id_medium  Num_ords  days_bet  days_bet_id
0  madinside  IML-0042758  2016-08-23    1190408         1         0            0
1  lisbeth19  IML-0071225  2017-02-26    1205650         1         0            0
2  lisbeth19  IML-0072944  2017-03-15    1207056         2        17            0
3  lisbeth19  IML-0077676  2017-05-12    1211395         3        75            0
4  lisbeth19  IML-0077676  2017-05-12    1207056         3        75           58
5  madinside  IML-0094979  2017-09-29    1222195         2       402            0
6  lisbeth19  IML-0099675  2017-11-15    1211446         4       262            0
7  lisbeth19  IML-0099690  2017-11-15    1225212         5       262            0
8  lisbeth19  IML-0101439  2017-12-02    1226511         6       279            0
9  lisbeth19  IML-0109883  2018-03-14    1226511         7       381          102
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. Looking at your df output, I think it might not exactly answer my quest: infact, column "Num_ords" at row 4 I should expect 3, because the order is the same (IML-0077676) with a double item (id_medium 1211395 and 1207056).
Also column "days_bet" seems not be what I would expect: infact value 58 at row 3 is the difference between the third and the second order by lisbeth19, where I would expect a difference between the third and the first.

Comment: @rafspo I think I understand the question better. Please see the update